# Getter on flutter error when different files

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make all strings in 1 file, but when I try it it produces an error `Only static members can be accessed in initializers`

I want to put all strings in 1 file and can be called with the getter method for all classes, be it an ordinary class, a class with StatefullWidget, and a class with StatelessWidget

error `Only static members can be accessed in initializers` leading to `configStrings` in the ApiService class

> My Code in config_string.dart

```
class ConfigStrings {
  String _blogUrl = "https://blogspot-to-app.blogspot.com/";

  String get blogUrl => _blogUrl;
}
```

> My Code in api_service.dart

```
import 'package:blogspot/config/config_strings.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

class ApiServices {
  var configStrings = ConfigStrings();
  final String baseUrl = configStrings.blogUrl;
  Client client = Client();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access `configStrings` inside a method or the constructor:

```
import 'package:blogspot/config/config_strings.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

class ApiServices {
  var configStrings = ConfigStrings();
  ApiServices(){
      final String baseUrl = configStrings.blogUrl;
  }  
 Client client = Client();
}
```